# Confusion with htaccess code rewriting rule. How it works. My code shows errors

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am beginer in the field htaccess and URL rewriting. Help me
My code :

```
www.example.com/education/education-centers.php
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges&Start-page=1
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges&DistrictName=Kannur
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges&DistrictName=Kannur&start=1//used for pagination
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges&DistrictName=Kannur&LocalityName=Taliparamba
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering colleges&DistrictName=Kannur&LocalityName=Taliparamba&start=1/used for pagination
www.example.com/education/education.php?Main=10&Id=12&Name=Sir Syed College Taliparamba
```

Also :
for Image printing from Subfolder i used
www.example.com/education/subfolder/7.jpg
Anyone help me correct htaccess code for rewriting.
My old code like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^education-centers education-centers.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&LocalityName=$4&start=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&start=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&LocalityName=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ eduS.php?MainId=$1&Id=$2&Name=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&start=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But problem is that image was not printing.. Allways image printing code leades to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [QSA,L]` and shows error.
Can Anyone suggest me a clean and accurate .htaccess code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` are only applicable for very next `RewriteRule` only so your rules are firing more than once for the same URI.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^education-centers/?$ education-centers.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&LocalityName=$4&start=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&start=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3&LocalityName=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ eduS.php?MainId=$1&Id=$2&Name=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&start=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2&DistrictName=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Why? You haven't explained what you fixed and why it wouldn't work

Comment: Ya added some explanation.

Comment: Nice one, that's better :)